# Custom Results Display in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I need to display the results of my school, I am not able to find any component for the same, now i started scratch code to display the results. 
How could i connect my scratch code to joomla templates ?

Thankyou

Comment: a little bit vague. Could you provide the code you have written to retreive and display the results.

Comment: I have just started to code, need to see the results on, where i can put that code though i can see the output ?

Comment: the code will go inside the `views/view_name/tmpl/default.php` file. You say tou couldn't find a component to suit your needs, but I'm still a little lost as to what you actually want. Could you be a little more specific please

Comment: Actually need to show the custom results, like if someone puts his/her roll number, then he/she can see the results like how much marks she/he secured in their test. Sounds clear now ?

Comment: Will you be registering users? If not, this "puts his/her roll number" system is open to a lot of abuse, unless roll numbers are *very* difficult to guess. If it were me, I'd tie the system into Joomla users - i.e. create an account for each student. Then build a component that displays the results of the currently logged-in user - how are you storing 'results' at the moment? Also, how will you/someone else update these results?

Comment: I have created a component finally. I am working on it, will get you notify once i did the job if did not get any error :)

Comment: yeah My component works extraordinary, Did not find out the way to upload the results via csv ? Any idea how can we import the results from csv fields are name, fname, rollnumber, dob, session, college

Thankyou

Comment: this code is really not working, any help please